# Phonegap barcode scanner IOS | Android

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am building a PhoneGap application that needs to have a bar code scanner. I just want to know if it possible to integrate bar code scan in PhoneGap application for iOS and Android.
I have already looked at the plugins on GitHub, but I do not know how to use them.

Can someone please share a link of example/sample code, or if someone used bar code scanner in  a PhoneGap can you please share a link?

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner There is also an explanation for how to use it

Comment: If you have a example code please share with us and what about ios.

Answer (score 1):

The Manatee Works [Barcode Scanner SDK](https://manateeworks.com/barcode-scanner-sdk) PhoneGap plugin can be found here: https://github.com/manateeworks/phonegap-mwbarcodescanner

The plugin supports Android, iOS, and Windows. UPC and EAN are free. Other symbologies can be evaluated for free. Our price is better than Scandit for the same quality (sometimes better). Our company is financially stable and not having to borrow money to survive.

(Disclaimer: I am a member of the Manatee Works team.)

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same and I have figured out the iOS part of it by following  [this](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/PhoneGap-BarcodeScanner-Example-iOS) . Currently working on the android version, will update about that too.